Bypass protection cloudflare using python cloudscraper
I need to get the HTML on the site where cloudflare is installed. I use cloudscraper and proxy. My code runs on a local server. When I run the script from the hosting, I get a 403 error. Why it works on a local server and does not work on a virtual hosting. There is no restriction on hosting
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(
        interpreter="nodejs",
        delay=random.uniform(2, 5),
        browser={
            "browser": "chrome",
            "platform": "ios",
            "desktop": False,
        },
    )
    proxy_url = ""
    proxy_username = ""
    proxy_password = ""
    try:
        while flag_page:
            first_response = scraper.get(
                url + str(number_page),
                proxies={
                    "http": f"http://{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@{proxy_url}",
                },
            )
            cookies_from_response = first_response.cookies
            response = scraper.get(
                url + str(number_page),
                proxies={
                    "http": f"http://{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@{proxy_url}",
                },
                cookies=cookies_from_response,
            )


At what point does it throw the 403 error?  Please include some debugging details.

Immediately, when I send get request to the hosting

I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for help bypassing the security of a website. If a website's owner doesn't want your bot accessing the website, why do you think you should be able to?

What's happening is that primarily, the target website blocks you because it thinks you are a bot. It operates locally because in a home network, the IP appears as a legitimate residential, public or corporate IP. However, when one uses a popular hosting solution such as AWS, GCP or Azure, those providers publish their IP addresses publicly. It can, thus, enable the target website to automatically add these IP ranges to a blacklist for easier identification and blocking of automated traffic

Thank you. I've been thinking about it. I have enabled paid private proxies. Why didn't this solve the problem? How to make it so that you simulate a real IP address when contacting a hosting service. I thought that connecting a proxy does it.
